# How to specify any host in php file?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have an application created in PHP and MySQL hosted on a linux server . I have a db.inc file in which i have to specify the IP of that machine. How can I do that?

The contents are :

```
if (preg_match('/^(10.80.112.141|127.0.0.1|localhost|desktop|laptop)$/i', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
    // this is for my PC
    $dbusername = 'abc';
    $dbuserpass = 'abc123!';
    $dbprefix   = null;
    $http_server         = null;
    $https_server        = null;
    $https_server_suffix = null;
    $GLOBALS['log_xml_document'] = true;
```

How can I specify the hostname in file ?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? different config for different ip ?

Comment: Actually i have to specify the IP of the machine which will host the application. I want that the application should fetch the hostname like $hostname itself because the application will be hosted on a machine whose IP is not known

Comment: This is a bit of a risktaker. How do you know that every machine does not have db located somewhere else? And why can't you use localhost if you KNOW that each machine will always host the db too?

Comment: You can use localhost or 127.0.0.1, which will point to the machine the script is being executed into...

Comment: to get the host you can use this $host= gethostname();

Comment: but with localhost it doesnot work

Comment: @aneesh : can i write the things that you have written in my file ?

Comment: @user3086014 I guess you want to set the hostname in somewhere in script and based on the hostname you wanted to execute db . is it correct ? please let me know

Comment: i just want that instead of specifying the hostname it should fetch the IP automatically. Its not working on localhost

Comment: @user3086014 To get ip of machine where the application is running you can use this function piece of code $ip = gethostbyname(gethostname()); Let me know if this works for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45365/discussion-between-aneesh-and-user3086014)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to a DBMS on a hosted machine, and it does not work with localhost, it is most unlikely it will work with the hostname: 99% of the hosts are configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) alone. Of the ones using a public interface, 99% **still** listen on localhost.

So before chasing IP issues, I'd try and make sure I can connect to the database with other means (command line, phpMyAdmin, ??)

But beware of the fact that you are weeding out localhost and 127.0.0.1 in you preg() match.

Comment: Did not get you. yeah its now working with localhost or 127.0.0.1 IP